# JavaScript Group By Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array_count_values for javascript instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217136/array-count-values-for-javascript-instead)

Let's say I have simple JavaScript array like the following:

```
var array = ['Car', 'Car', 'Truck', 'Boat', 'Truck'];
```

I want to group and count of each so I would expect a key/value map of:

```
{
  Car   : 2,
  Truck : 2,
  Boat  : 1
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var arr = [ 'Car', 'Car', 'Truck', 'Boat', 'Truck' ];
var hist = {};
arr.map( function (a) { if (a in hist) hist[a] ++; else hist[a] = 1; } );
console.log(hist);
```

results in

```
{ Car: 2, Truck: 2, Boat: 1 }
```

This works, too:

```
hist = arr.reduce( function (prev, item) { 
  if ( item in prev ) prev[item] ++; 
  else prev[item] = 1; 
  return prev; 
}, {} );
```

Comment: first solution doesn't work for values that are not compatible with variable names like GUID or integers, though it is great

Comment: Just a note, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map map creates a copy of the array. In your case you're not even using that copy, so it will be better to doe is like so: arr.forEach(function (a) { if (a in hist) hist[a] ++; else hist[a] = 1; }) because forEach will not create a new copy

Comment: If you are using Undescore, instead of `arr.reduce` you can also try _.countBy(list, iterator) http://underscorejs.org/#countBy

Comment: thanks for exampla of creating dict out of array with reduce

Comment: You should use `Array.prototype.forEach()` instead of `Array.prototype.map()` in your first solution.

Comment: Can tidy it up with  arr.map((a) =>  a in hist ? hist[a] ++ : hist[a] = 1);

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through each index and save it in a dictionary and increment it when every that key is found.

```
count = {};
for(a in array){
  if(count[array[a]])count[array[a]]++;
  else count[array[a]]=1;
}
```

Output will be:

```
Boat: 1
Car: 2
Truck: 2
```