# Get all unique items and show number of same ones in JS

Tags: javascript

What i mean is, imagine i have this data

```
const data = [
  { name: 'Apple', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Orange', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Banana', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Milk', category: 'drink' },
  { name: 'Juice', category: 'drink' },
];
```

What i want is to show unique categories and show number of same items

```
[
  { count: 3, category: 'fruit' },
  { count: 2, category: 'drink' },
]
```

Comment: Python has a similar implementation for this called a Counter. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320253/is-there-a-javascript-function-similar-to-the-python-counter-function) is another post that you could follow to implement this if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to do but it should work

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Apple', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Orange', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Banana', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Milk', category: 'drink' },
  { name: 'Juice', category: 'drink' },
];

function filterArray(arr) {
    const map = new Map()
    arr.map(i => map.set(i.category, map.get(i.category) + 1 || 1))
    return [...map].map(i => ({'count': i[1],'category': i[0]}))
}

let result = filterArray(data)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: There is already a filter function for arrays in JS, why create your own one?

Comment: how do i get the count with filter ?

Answer (score 2):

One Solution is leveraging JS Set to find out unique category and use it to get the count.

```
const data = [
  { name: 'Apple', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Orange', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Banana', category: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'Milk', category: 'drink' },
  { name: 'Juice', category: 'drink' },
];

const categories = new Set();

data.forEach((item) => {
    categories.add(item.category);
})

const result = [];
categories.forEach((category) => {
    const val = data.filter((item) => item.category === category);
  
  result.push({count: val.length, category})
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpfull. I did this to put all it together: ```[...new Set(data.map(dt=>dt.category))].map(d => {
    const val = data.filter(item => item.category === d)
    return {category:d, count:val.length}
})```

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov It is looping through 3 times, why did you accept this answer over the solution below ?