# How do I count the number of occurrences of a word in a string/store it in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to write a function that when given a string, returns an object where each key is a word in the given string, with its value being how many times that word appeared in the given string.

Here's what I have:

```
function countWords(str) {
  var strArray = str.split(' ');
  var output = {};

  if(str.length === 0) {
    return output;
  } else {
    strArray.map(function(n) {
      output[n] = str.split(n).length - 1;
    });
  }
  return output;
}
```

Here's the console output when I add...

```
console.log(strArray);
console.log(output);
```

...to the code:

> Object {
>     a: 4,
>     ask: 1,
>     bunch: 3,
>     get: 1,
>     try: 1
>   }
>   ["ask", "a", "bunch", "try", "a", "bunch", "get", "a", "bunch"]

For some reason, the number of occurrences of 'a' is 1 too high but all the others are correct.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the function being called with? What input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting words in javascript and push it into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102199/counting-words-in-javascript-and-push-it-into-an-object)

Comment: Although I'm not sure it's actually a duplicate after re-reading this question. This one is "I have an algorithm and it doesn't work correctly" instead of "I don't have an algorithm". The title misled me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do

```
str.split(n)
```

if `n` is short, especially if it's a single character, like `a`, then likely occurrences of it *inside* of other words in the string will be split as well. For example, `'abc a abc'.split('a')` will result in an array of length 4 even though there's only one `a` in the string.

One possible step towards a solution would be to use a regular expression, and put word boundaries around the word:

```
output[n] = str.split(new RegExp(String.raw`\b${n}\b`)).length - 1
```

But it would be more elegant not to use intermediate arrays, and use `reduce` instead:

```js
const countWords = str => str.split(' ').reduce((a, word) => {
  a[word] = (a[word] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(countWords('ask a bunch, try a bunch, get a bunch'));
```

Comment: I ended up using Jonas Wilms's answer because it was the simplest. However, I found yours very helpful as well cause it allowed me to research some technologies I haven't used before. Thank you very much!

Comment: `.map` is not appropriate at all when you're not going to use the mapped result - `.reduce` *is* the right method to use when you need to reduce an array into a single object.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for keeping me on track.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the inner split just increase the count by one:

```
 strArray.forEach(function(n) {
  output[n] = (output[n] || 0) + 1;
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

To count no of occurrences of word, given string can be split by space or you can use to read word by word using space as a delimiter.

Here is the sample example in java, in this example java Scanner class is used to read word by word from a given input stream, if the word matches, counter values will be incremented.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordOccurrencesInGivenString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "try";
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int counter = 0;
            String str = null;
            do {
                str = s.next();
                if (str.equals(word)) {
                    ++counter;
                }
            } while (!str.equals("exit"));
            System.out.println("No of occurrences of a word [" + word + "] : " + counter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in this example "exit" word is used to stop the reading of data from input stream and to print the no of occurrences of a word.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. OP is trying to debug his *Javascript* program.