# how to calculate the number of similar string parts/chunks from a string?

Tags: javascript, php, string

I have a string like this : `33,33,56,89,56`

I need to find out how to calculate the number of similar strings parts in that string using both JavaScript?

like for `33,33,56,89,56` how many '33's and how many `56`s are there? using  JavaScript? 
The split or match wont work here. actually the scenario is: There are several buttons having the same class and one custom attribute price here for product rows. Now on click event i am fetching the value like this `$('.product_row').attr('price');` , now i need to calculate what product is being clicked here and how many times? and i need to calculate if it is a similar product being clicked , how many times it is being clicked?

So, it 33,33,56,89,56 this string will be generated dynamically.

Help here guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about javascript, but here is PHP:

```
$data = "33,33,56,89,56";    
$dataAsArray = explode(",", $data);
$valueCount = array_count_values($dataAsArray);
echo $valueCount[56]; // Should output 2
```

Edit:
As for JavaScript, have a look here:
[array_count_values for JavaScript instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217136/array-count-values-for-javascript-instead)

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a test';
echo strlen($text); // 14

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

// the string is reduced to 's is a test', so it prints 1
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3);

// the text is reduced to 's i', so it prints 0
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3, 3);

// generates a warning because 5+10 > 14
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 5, 10);


// prints only 1, because it doesn't count overlapped substrings
$text2 = 'gcdgcdgcd';
echo substr_count($text2, 'gcdgcd');
?>
```

JS:

```
var foo = 'This is a test';
var count = foo.match(/is/g);
console.log(count.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php 
$str = "33,33,56,89,56,56";
echo substr_count($str, '56');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var temp = "33,33,56,89,56,56";
var count = temp.match(/56/g);  
alert(count.length);
</script>
```