# Sum the second parameter of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object, which I need to add up to a number of times words appear. Ex:

```
{
step1: ["luiz"]
step2: ["pedro"]
step3: ["luiz"]
step4: ["luiz"]
step5: ["luiz"]
}
```

I tried using .map, .forEach, .filter, but they all come back undefined.

**.filter**

```
let irmas = answers.filter((answer) => answer[1] === 'luiz)
```

**.map**

```
let contagemRespostas = answers.map(function(answer, index) {
      return contagemRespostas.index
    })
```

How do I get names only and add values?

EDIT:

The return is something like:

`{ 'luiz': 3, 'pedro': 2 }` or the highest value `{ 'luiz': 3 }`

Comment: `I tried using .map, .forEach, .filter, but they all come back undefined.` - Please share any/all of these attempts. Sounds like you might just be forgetting to `return` within the predicate. Your question could also use with a bit of clarification. What is your desired result?

Comment: Can you please show your desired output?

Comment: is it possible for the arrays to have multiple values?

Comment: something like this might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929965/2280670

drop that sort of code and loop over the object keys

Comment: edit the main question

Comment: still use some form of the code i commented above and then combine the resulting objects

Comment: I tried to use, but o got nothing on console.log. `var count = respostas.reduce((a,c)=> (a[c]=++a[c]||1,a) ,{});
    console.log(count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a reduce to create an object with the values

```js
const data = {
  step1: ["luiz"],
  step2: ["pedro"],
  step3: ["luiz"],
  step4: ["luiz"],
  step5: ["luiz"],
}
    
const result = Object.values(data).flat().reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.hasOwnProperty(cur) ? acc[cur]++ : acc[cur] = 1
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result) // {luiz: 4, pedro: 1}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! How i can get only the numbers out of the reduce?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bwmfhqev/2/

```
var foo = {
    step1: ["luiz"],
    step2: ["pedro"],
    step3: ["luiz"],
    step4: ["luiz"],
    step5: ["luiz"]
}

let result = {};

console.log(Object.keys(foo));

// loop over the keys of the object
for(var key of Object.keys(foo)) {
    // get the number of occurrences of words in the array for each key
    let count= foo[key].reduce((a,c)=> (a[c]=++a[c]||1,a) ,{});
  //combine everything into 1 object
  for(var key2 of Object.keys(count)) {
    console.log(count[key2]);
    if(key2 in result) {
        result[key2] = result[key2] + count[key2];
    }
    else {
        result[key2] = count[key2];
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

The idea here to process each key in the original object. and then create an object out of each one that gets the number of occurrences of each word for each key. Then combine them all into 1 object